# Is it possible to override type registration

Tags: asp.net, autofac

I have a type registered in a module:

```
moduleBuilder.RegisterType<Service>().As<Interface>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Which I would like to override in a different module so that the original service is not used solution-wide.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

"If more than one component exposes the same service, Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service."[[1]](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation#Default_Registrations)

So if you register your AnotherService after default Service it will override it.

```
// In Module1
moduleBuilder.RegisterType<Service>().As<Interface>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// In Module2
// AnotherService overrides Service
moduleBuilder.RegisterType<AnotherService>().As<Interface>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

One subtle moment: if you don't control or don't want to control the sequence of registration of modules then you can use `PreserveExistingDefaults()` modifier in default Service registration which avoids overriding the default implementation.

```
// In Module1
moduleBuilder.RegisterType<Service>()
    .As<Interface>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
    .PreserveExistingDefaults();

// In Module2
// AnotherService overrides Service
moduleBuilder.RegisterType<AnotherService>().As<Interface>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then the sequence of registration won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autofac's [identification of services by name](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices#By_Name). For example,

```
builder.RegisterType<MorningService>()
    .As<IGreetingService>()
    .Named<IGreetingService>("morning")
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<EveningService>()
    .As<IGreetingService>()
    .Named<IGreetingService>("evening")
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<MorningController>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IGreetingService>("morning"))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<EveningController>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IGreetingService>("evening"))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();

// ***** You can even pass it to other service *****
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IGreetingService>("evening"))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

### Interface

```
public interface IGreetingService
{
    string GetMessage();
}
```

### Services

```
public class MorningService : IGreetingService
{
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "Have a good morning!";
    }
}

public class EveningService : IGreetingService
{
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "Have a good evening!";
    }
}
```

### Evening Controller

```
public class EveningController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGreetingService _service;

    public EveningController(IGreetingService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Evening/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = _service.GetMessage();
        return View();
    }
}
```